# AWS Sagemaker ValueError: Unsupported dtype object on array when using strings and dates

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

I have a CSV file I'm trying to RCF on.  If I put a date or string in the CSV then I get an error like the one below.  If I limit it to just the integer and float fields the script runs fine.  Is there some way to process dates and string?  I see the taxi example from AWS and it has dates which appear the same as mine

```
eventData = pd.read_csv(data_location, delimiter=",", header=None, parse_dates=True)

print('Starting RCF Training')
# specify general training job information
rcf = RandomCutForest(role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                      instance_count=1,
                      instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
                      data_location=data_location,
                      output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
                      base_job_name="ad-rcf",
                      num_samples_per_tree=512,
                      num_trees=50)

rcf.fit(rcf.record_set(eventData.values))
```

CSV Data that fails

```
392507,1613744,1/2/2020 19:11,1577238693,2469,3.30E+01,-9.67E+01
691381,1888551,12/10/2019 9:22,1575641745,3460,2.37E+01,9.04E+01
392507,1613744,1/2/2020 19:20,1577236815,1797,3.30E+01,-9.67E+01
392507,1613744,1/29/2020 19:04,1577264188,1797,3.30E+01,-9.67E+01
```

Error output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-ba19bf5d66a2> in <module>
---> 21 rcf.fit(rcf.record_set(eventData.values))
     22 
     23 print('Done RCF Training')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/amazon/amazon_estimator.py in record_set(self, train, labels, channel, encrypt)
    281         logger.debug("Uploading to bucket %s and key_prefix %s", bucket, key_prefix)
    282         manifest_s3_file = upload_numpy_to_s3_shards(
--> 283             self.instance_count, s3, bucket, key_prefix, train, labels, encrypt
    284         )
    285         logger.debug("Created manifest file %s", manifest_s3_file)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/amazon/amazon_estimator.py in upload_numpy_to_s3_shards(num_shards, s3, bucket, key_prefix, array, labels, encrypt)
    443                 s3.Object(bucket, key_prefix + file).delete()
    444         finally:
--> 445             raise ex
    446 
    447 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/amazon/amazon_estimator.py in upload_numpy_to_s3_shards(num_shards, s3, bucket, key_prefix, array, labels, encrypt)
    424                     write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(file, shard, label_shards[shard_index])
    425                 else:
--> 426                     write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(file, shard)
    427                 file.seek(0)
    428                 shard_index_string = str(shard_index).zfill(len(str(len(shards))))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/amazon/common.py in write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(file, array, labels)
    154             )
    155         resolved_label_type = _resolve_type(labels.dtype)
--> 156     resolved_type = _resolve_type(array.dtype)
    157 
    158     # Write each vector in array into a Record in the file object

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/amazon/common.py in _resolve_type(dtype)
    288     if dtype == np.dtype("float32"):
    289         return "Float32"
--> 290     raise ValueError("Unsupported dtype {} on array".format(dtype))
    291 
    292 

ValueError: Unsupported dtype object on array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue, the RCF can't handle dates and strings.  There's this page for the Kenesis offering from AWS that covers the same Random Cut Forest algorithm https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sqlrf-random-cut-forest.html  It says the function only supports "The algorithm accepts the DOUBLE, INTEGER, FLOAT, TINYINT, SMALLINT, REAL, and BIGINT data types."

The gotcha part that AWS does with the NYC Taxi example is they use .value which is referring to only the value column of the data.  They are basically dropping the dates from the RCF as a feature.  It doesn't help that .values on the array does work and looks very similar to .value